# Can this cyclic inequality be solved using SOS/dumbassing?

Tags: inequality

I got an inequality to this form and I was wondering wether I could solve it using SOS.

a,b,c are nonnegative.

$\sum (a-b)^2(3c-a-b) \ge 0$

Written using the chinese dumbass notation it looks like this:

[image]

Can this be solved using SOS/dumbassing or any other method really

Comment: For the baffled: https://www.tjhsst.edu/~2010bhamrick/files/dumbassing.pdf

Comment: This is wrong (if I didn't make a mistake)! Try $a=b=c/4>0$.

Comment: It's -9, my bad

Comment: The inequality is indeed wrong, replacing the -1's with +1's and the -9 with a -15 would fix it

Comment: The link is now down, but https://web.archive.org/web/20191209184102/https://www.tjhsst.edu/~2010bhamrick/files/dumbassing.pdf

Answer (score 0):

From [this comment](http://s/3497468/can-this-cyclic-inequality-be-solved-using-sos-dumbassing#comment7192550_3497468) I'm assuming the triangle should be this

$$\begin{array}{ccccccc}
  &   &   & 1   &   &   &   \\
  &   & 2 &     & 2 &   &   \\
  & 2 &   & -15 &   & 2 &   \\
1 &   & 2 &     & 2 &   & 1
\end{array}
$$

Hence the equation is $a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+2ab^2-15abc+2ac^2+b^3+2b^2c+2bc^2+c^3$. We can simply use AM-GM

$$a^3+2a^2b+2a^2c+2ab^2-15abc+2ac^2+b^3+2b^2c+2bc^2+2c^3 \ge 15[(a^3)(a^2b)(a^2b)(a^2c)(a^2c)(ab^2)(ab^2)(ac^2)(ac^2)(b^3)(b^2c)(b^2c)(bc^2)(bc^2)(c^3)]^{1/15} - 15abc = 15abc-15abc=0$$

Hence the inequality is proven